# A button which would stop the program when pressed in python with tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, exit

Is it possible in python with the use of tkinter to have a button which would, when pressed, stop the program completely, not only closing the window but would stop it ?

I tried 2 different ways of doing it. Both by importing sys.

First one :

```
import sys

#the rest of my program

    boutonstart = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=parfenetre, text="Quitter",fg_color="red", font=("helvetica", 20, "bold"), command=sys.exit())
```

Second one would be something along the lines of :

```
def leavee() :
    sys.exit()  

boutonstart = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=parfenetre, text="Quitter",fg_color="red", font=("helvetica", 20, "bold"), command=leavee())
```

Both of those solutions seems to work at the beginning but as soon as the window with the button comes up on the screen, it does not respond, freezing everything and forcing me to close the windows and restart the program.

**Edit :

Here is the entire code of my window in which I try to put the button :

```
# Crée la fenêtre des paramètres du démineur 
def parDemineur():

    parfenetre = Tk()    
    
    #Assigne pour titre à la fenêtre "Paramètres du Jeu du Démineur"
    parfenetre.title("Paramètres du Jeu du démineur") 
    
    #Image du démineur
    Pardemineursource = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=parfenetre, file='ParDemineur.png')

    #Affiche l'image
    Pardemineurimg = Label(parfenetre, image = Pardemineursource)
    
    #Gère la position du message de prévention
    Pardemineurimg.pack()

    #Change la taille afin que la fenêtre puisse tout afficher
    parfenetre.minsize(400, 900)
    parfenetre.maxsize(400, 400)

    # Gère la création de la fenêtre avec sa largeur, sa hauteur, son fond)
    canvas = Canvas(parfenetre , width =750, height=500 , background='white')
    canvas.pack()
    
    #Place la fenêtre au centre de l'écran
    parfenetre.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
    
    # Utilise CTkButton à la place du bouton de Tkinter, permettant plus de personnalisation. Le bouton une fois appuyé, permet de fermer la fenêtre des paramètres.
    boutonstart = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=parfenetre, text="Commencer à jouer !", font=("helvetica", 20, "bold"), command=parfenetre.destroy)
    
    #Situe le bouton dans la fenêtre ainsi que sa taille
    boutonstart.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9,relheight=0.125, relwidth=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

    # Utilise CTkButton à la place du bouton de Tkinter, permettant plus de personnalisation. Le bouton une fois appuyé, permet de fermer la fenêtre des paramètres.
    boutonfermer = customtkinter.CTkButton(parfenetre, text="Quitter",fg_color="red", font=("helvetica", 20, "bold"), command=sys.exit)
    
    #Situe le bouton dans la fenêtre ainsi que sa taille
    boutonfermer.place(relx=0.94, rely=0.08,relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.08, anchor=CENTER)

    #Affiche le texte de prévention avec ses caractéristiques
    ContenuPar = Label(parfenetre, text="Choix de Difficulté :", font=("helvetica", 10, "bold"))
 
    #Gère la position du message de difficulté
    ContenuPar.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)   
 
    #Force la fenêtre à être ouverte en pleine écran
    parfenetre.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    # Attend que la fenêtre se ferme pour continuer le code
    parfenetre.wait_window(parfenetre)
    
    parfenetre.mainloop

parDemineur()
```

For now when boutonfermer is pressed, nothing happens but when you pass to the next window of the program (containing a mine sweeper game) it just crashes and the window doesn't respond anymore. This only happens when "command=" is linked to sys.exit or a function containing it.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the command attribute of the CTkButton, you should pass the function name without the parentheses. So instead of command=sys.exit() or command=leavee(), it should be command=sys.exit or command=leavee. This way, the function will only be called when the button is pressed.

For example:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk

def leavee():
    sys.exit()

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=leavee)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it still doesn't work, whether it be command=sys.exit or command=leavee with the function getting defined before both don't do anything when the button get pressed, moreover the window that follows the one with the button just crashes. I just edited the post with the entire code of the window in which I try to put the button, keep in mind that there are multiple windows in the program which opens up each time one gets closed, like a linear path, but if I shall press the button it should stop the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
root.destroy()
```

where root is your root window.

**Example**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def open_new():
    child = tk.Toplevel(root)
    
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Open new window', command=open_new)
b1.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Exit application', command=root.destroy)
b2.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

The <kbd>Exit application</kbd> button will close all application windows, if they are `Toplevel` widgets.

If you have implemented the child windows as `Tk()` instances you will have to keep references to all of them and then delete them one at a time when exiting.

Comment: Yes but I have multiple windows, so if I destroy this window it will just open the next one, I want to be able to destroy them all at once :)

Comment: Added explanation and example